# Storing nearest neighbor

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

There are algorithms out there to find `k` nearest neighbors in many ways. I am eventually will have to apply these, however in my case, I can code my program to add points one-by-one rather than add all the points altogether, then run a algorithm. Is this make the problem easier, so that maybe I could use a tree, and add each node to a *neighborhood tree* or something. This seems like it would be faster than searching all the points linearly.

And in my program points will be moving constantly, so I will be required to update neighbors, that's why I thought it is better to use a tree or another construct to update records, rather than calculate nearest neighbors in every movement of these points. Do you know of such data structure ?

Comment: _"points will be moving constantly"_ - then when is it a neighbour and when is it near? This sounds like it contradicts your _"this make the problem easier"_.  But otherwise, consider a Max Heap.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4274218/238978

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a graph datastructure/database is most appropriate due to the structural similarity.
Example: https://neo4j.com/graphgist/a7c915c8-a3d6-43b9-8127-1836fecc6e2f (I do not work for neo4j)