# Does sklearn kNN (NearestNeighbors) do batch processing?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, batch-processing, knn

I'm using knn algorithm from sklearn to train on a dataset. I wonder can we do batch processing here, if my dataset contains millions of rows?

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=6, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(new_features)
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(new_features)
```

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not in sklearn. Batch processing is algorithm-specific. For example, there is [MiniBatchKMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans) or [SGDClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html). There is no batch version of kNN however.

The main reason being the requirement of fast neighbour search for arbitrary point. For this, usually KD-tree or Ball-tree is used, which requires extra-work to maintain its properties in batch training. You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4274218/9632441) and the corresponding [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4464297/9632441) for more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`NearestNeighbors` is an instance based algorithm. When you give a test data point it calculates the similarity to the train train using some similarity method like shortest distance. So in reality there is no learning happening in the `NearestNeighbors` algorithm. During the fit phase it creates data structures to arrange the train data in such a way that searching during prediction will be faster. So no, you cannot do batch processing like you do in neural networks.

In general, the ML algorithms which does not use gradient decent optimization to train the weights cannot be batched. Take for example `decision trees`, you need the the full train dataset to calculate certain values (say gini index) to decide how to build a train. So no, for decision trees you cannot do batch processing.

Comment: Decision tree is a bad example because there's ID5R and Incremental CART algorithms that allow for instance-based training. Source: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Batch-and-Incremental-Learning-of-Decision-Trees-He/417aad0ee5fd1382fdedf4b28657c8de5c6add73